# React UseFetch cannot retreive json data from error response

Tags: reactjs, custom-error-handling

I am still quite new to React, I was trying to create some dynamic content and managing Errors with Usefetch.

getting data from 20x response codes is fine.
however when response code is error (40x, 50x) I cannot get the response body.

here for example my reponse replies status 400: Bad request: content-type "application/json"
`{ message: "My Custom Error Message" }`

```
import React from "react";
import {useFetch} from "react-async";


const Feedback = () => {

  const myRequest= useFecth("my_api_url");

  if (myRequest.isPending)
    return("Be Patient"); // works fine

  if (myRequest.isFullfilled)
    return(myRequest.data.myJsonObject); // works fine

  if (myRequest.isRejected)
    return(myRequest.error.message); // only shows 400 bad request

  return(null); // request was not sent yet, don't bother
}
```

I can't seem to find the body in `myRequest.error`, and `myRequest.data` is empty (since `myRequest.isRejected`)

Is there a way to retreive response body when the http status code is error?

Comment: `myRequest.IsPending` => `myRequest.isPending`, no? Surely the hook doesn't use a capital `I` there?

Comment: Wow, the [documentation](https://docs.react-async.com/api/state) for that is *sparse*.  It's clear that `error` will not be what you want, but I'm not immediately seeing a way to tget it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response:

Regaring library versions, reading my package.json:

```
"dependancies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-async": "^10.0.1"
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import {useFetch} from "react-async";


const Feedback = () => {

  const myRequest= useFecth("my_api_url");

  if (myRequest.isPending)
    return("Be Patient"); // works fine

  if (myRequest.isFullfilled)
    return("data: " + myRequest.data.myJsonObject);
  if (myRequest.isRejected)
    return("error: " + myRequest.data.myJsonObject); // OUCH!

  return(null); // request was not sent yet, don't bother
}
```

I seperated Fullfilled and Rejected status because it fits the idea of what I want to do.

I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myRequest.data is undefined` which is what I understood from the [react-async documentation](https://docs.react-async.com/api/state):

```
data
any
Last resolved promise value, maintained when new error arrives.
```

data is updated only when isFullfilled.
error is updated only when isRejected.

Moreover `JSON.stringify(myRequest.value)` returns `{"response": {}}`

Answer (score -1):

**Final solution:**

I attempted to run this code locally and it seems, that this is not possible to be done via `react-async` lib. I also tested `axios` lib with the same result. It seems like using built-in `fetch()` method is only solution to your problem.

**Old attempt of fix:**

Can you tell which exactly library are you using?

The problem is that you are reading `Response.error.message` and in case of error, it's expected to receive "400 bad request". Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import {useFetch} from "react-async";


const Feedback = () => {

  const myRequest = useFetch("my_api_url");

  if (myRequest.isPending)
    return("Be Patient"); // works fine

  if (myRequest.isFullfilled || myRequest.isRejected)
    return(Response.data.myJsonObject); // should show response body (even if it was an error response)

  return(null); // request was not sent yet, don't bother
}
```

EDIT: Fixed obvious typo - `IsPending` -> `isPending`
EDIT2: Another typo: `useFecht` -> `useFetch`